# SQLite DB closed after prepare but stmt still works?

Tags: sqlite

Also, the sqlite_master table for DB and registered functions still seem available. Is this just a case of the stmt accessing memory that hasn't been overwritten yet or does the prepare write details into the stmt that means it doesn't subsequently require the sqlite3* structure.

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Odd(sqlite3_context *ctx,int nargs,sqlite3_value **values)
{
    sqlite3_result_int(ctx,sqlite3_value_int(values[0])%2);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int _tmain(int argc,_TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *DB;
    if (sqlite3_open_v2("c:/SQLiteData/MyDB.db",&DB,SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE,NULL)!=SQLITE_OK)
        return 1;
    sqlite3_create_function_v2(DB,"Odd",-1,SQLITE_UTF16 | SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC,NULL,
    &Odd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    if (sqlite3_prepare16_v2(DB,L"select * from sqlite_master where Odd(rowid)",
    -1,&stmt,NULL)!=SQLITE_OK) return 2;
    if (sqlite3_close_v2(DB)!=SQLITE_OK) return 3;
    int Count=0;
    while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) Count++;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) says:

> If the database connection is associated with unfinalized prepared statements … then sqlite3_close() will leave the database connection open and return SQLITE_BUSY. If sqlite3_close_v2() is called with unfinalized prepared statements …, then the database connection becomes an unusable "zombie" which will automatically be deallocated when the last prepared statement is finalized or the last sqlite3_backup is finished. The sqlite3_close_v2() interface is intended for use with host languages that are garbage collected, and where the order in which destructors are called is arbitrary.

But you are not using such a language.
You should not try to access the zombie; your application

> should finalize all prepared statements … associated with the sqlite3 object prior to attempting to close the object.

Comment: Thanks CL. I hadn't read that and was thrown by the fact it returned SQLITE_OK.